# How to update avatar in buddypress programmatically?

Tags: buddypress, avatar

How to update avatar in buddypress programmatically? I have a script, which gets the image url and I want to update the url in the database, so that that image will will be avatar of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does not save the value of the avatar image in any database. It looks in the file system for avatar image and displays it on the website.

So, I am planning to download the image to the server, which is running the WordPress (BuddyPress). I need to create a directory with the name same as user ID, in the directory /wp-content/uploads/avatars/ and put two images, one as -bpfull.jpg (full image) and -bpthumb.jpg (thumbnail image). And these images will be displayed for that user, automatically.

Comment: Sorry I flagged this as not being an answer in error.

Comment: I am looking same logic which you explained in this topic. If you have done avatar upload programmatically can you please share your logic with me. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Happy It's a long time back and I don't remember how I resolved it.